# Yacc grammar expressions, conflicts

Tags: parsing, grammar, yacc

Can someone identify where the grammar conflict is in this expression production?

```
expr '+' expr 
|
expr '-' expr
|
expr '*' expr
|
expr '/' expr
|
expr '(' ')'
|
T_IDENTIFIER
|
T_STRING_LITERAL
|
T_INTEGER_LITERAL
|
T_FLOAT_LITERAL
```

I'm trying to implement function calls taking an `expr` as the operand, so for example, the following would be valid grammar:

```
1()
1.5()
"STRING"()
fn()
```

Comment: The Yacc metalanguage is not BNF. You need to post the errors you are getting.

Comment: This is basically the standard "calculator" example you see in a lot of Yacc and Bison books. If you read about that example online, you'll find that it always has the problem of: what do you do with an expression that has more than one operator, like 1+2*3-4? Since all your rules are simple ones with one operator, like "expr: expr+expr", Yacc will have to apply several of them in a row. What order should it do that in?  And so there'll be a big discussion of "precedence." Explaining precedence is way too long for us to do in a comment -- I recommend you go search about calculators in Yacc.